# How to customize lifecycle environment name as part of docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker-compose

How to customize lifecycle environment name as part of docker-compose.yaml. I would like to specify the environment name in .env file and I want it to reflect in the docker-compose.yaml but this is not getting reflected properly

```
volumes:
  elasticsearch-data-dev:

networks:
  elasticsearch-network-dev:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple bash script:

#### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app_${MYENV}:
    image: busybox
    container_name: app_${MYENV}
    networks:
    - network_${MYENV}
    
  networks:
    network_${MYENV}:
```

#### run.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
MYENV=${1}
COMPOSE=`eval "echo \"$(cat docker-compose.yaml)\""`
echo "$COMPOSE" | docker-compose -f - up
```

```sh
./run.sh dev
./run.sh prod
```

#### Example run:

```sh
$ ./run.sh dev
Starting app_dev ... done
$ docker ps
f33b113f9d2b ... app_dev
$ docker network ls
436386f4eb80        demo_network_dev    bridge              local
```

Comment: network_${MYENV}: will this translation in the last line work as per your suggestion, it doesn't tokenize properly

Comment: I added an example run. It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use env variables to do this. Docker has a nice writeup about this here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Essentially, you need to define your .env file and replace your `docker-compose.yaml` with the correct variables. If you need to, you can have multiple .env copies (.env.dev or .env.stg), but you will need to pass an additional argument to `docker-compose` (`--env-file`) to point to the correct configuration.

Your .env file would look something like this:

```
ES_DATA=dev-data
ES_NETWORK=dev-network
```

Your yaml file would look something like this:

```
volumes:
  elasticsearch-data-dev: "${ES_DATA}"

networks:
  elasticsearch-network-dev: "${ES_NETWORK}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, elasticsearch-network-dev is the variable  which needs to be replaced dynamically. You don't need to specify anything on the right hand side for a network name

Answer (score 0):

I might combine two less-common Compose features here.

Write a main `docker-compose.yml` file that reflects the set of things you might want to run in the production deploy.  Do not include any `build:` lines, but do include `image:` references to your registry.  Do not mention any environment in this file.  Also, do not override the `container_name:` or the `name:` of any images or volumes you create.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml (main)
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.12.0
    volumes: ['elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data']
  app:
    image: registry.example.com/my/app:${TAG:-latest}
    environment: { ELASTICSEARCH_URL: 'http://elasticsearch:9200' }
    ports: ['8000:8000']
volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

Compose supports a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name).  If you set the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable or the `docker-compose -p` command-line option, this name (defaults to the current directory name) will be included in all of the generated names.

```sh
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=prod
docker-compose up -d
docker ps             # prod_elasticsearch_1, prod_app_1
docker volume ls      # prod_elasticsearch-data
```

You can also launch Compose with [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files); if you do, these are combined together, and you can specify multiple options for the same service.  In development for example you might want to publish ports for the database and specify that the app needs to be built:

```yaml
# docker-compose.dev.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    ports: ['9200:9200', '9300:9300']
    # all other settings come from main docker-compose.yml
  app:
    build: .
```

Then to launch this you need both Compose files.

```sh
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=dev
docker-compose up -d -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml
docker ps     # dev_elasticsearch_1, etc., also prod_* if still running
```

If you do this frequently, you can imagine writing a shell-script wrapper to handle this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
env="$1"
shift
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME="$env"
if [ -f "docker-compose.$env.yml" ]; then
  export COMPOSE_FILE="docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.$env.yml"
fi
exec docker-compose "$@"
```

```sh
./compose-env.sh dev \
  up -d
```

Comment: Using different compose files for each environment is a better approach than my answer. However, it is pain to manage with increased service count.